# Error Minecraft: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Tags: 14.04, java, minecraft

Since I've installed the Jave DevelopmentKit, this error shows up everytime I try to run the game

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option UseConcMarkSweepGC; support was removed in 14.0
Unrecognized VM option 'CMSIncrementalMode'`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Look, what i've done was: I've moved the JDK's folder away from java's folder and paste somewhere in my computer. I guess you instaled JDK to create apps right? Try to do it, move the JDK's folder, later if you need that folder again, simply add the new path to whatever aplication you want. Just move the folder certainly will work and your game will back to normal.